# Error al serializar los datos recibidos de un servicio web swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode, ios8

Buenos dias me gustaria que me ayudaran por favor, tengo un servicio web en Swift 2 me retorna un array asi

> {"message": "Imagen Almacenada con Exito." "error": false}

pero a la hora de serializarlo

```
 do{
     let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(nsdata, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
   }catch{
          print(error)
          }
```

me muestra el siguiente error:

> { Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." }

Answer (score 0):

Por un lado, el string JSON que has pasado le falta una coma entr eel final del `message` y el inicio del `error`. Es decir, tienes:

`con Exito." "error": false}`

y debería de ser:

`con Exito.", "error": false}`

Por otro lado, arreglando ese error y dejando las opciones a cero con `[]` a mi me funciona en un `Playground` con el siguiente código sin ningún error:

```
var str = "{\"message\": \"Imagen Almacenada con Exito.\", \"error\": false}"
var nsdata = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

do {

    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(nsdata, options: [])

} catch {

    print(error)

}
```

**Actualización 1**

En caso de no funcionar, prueba con la opción `AllowFragments`

```
do {

    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(nsdata, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)

} catch {

    print(error)

}
```

Comment: no puedo modificar eso ese str que copiaste viene del servicio web osea viene un json

Comment: Pues entonces tienes un problema, porque eso no es un JSON válido por faltarle la coma y muy probablemente te falle por esa razón. Entra en http://jsonlint.com y copia el texto que has puesto y dale a `Validate JSON`. Verás tú mismo que no es válido y por eso te falle.

Comment: nada no sirvio y si, si viene con la coma...

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, pero es raro raro...